# How do I save a Huggingface dataset?

Tags: huggingface-datasets, huggingface

How do I write a HuggingFace dataset to disk?

I have made my own HuggingFace dataset using a JSONL file:

> Dataset({
> features: ['id', 'text'],
> num_rows: 18 })

I would like to persist the dataset to disk.

Is there a preferred way to do this? Or, is the only option to use a general purpose library like joblib or pickle?

Comment: Might help: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/saving-dataset-in-the-current-state-without-cache/5892

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can save a HuggingFace dataset to disk using the `save_to_disk()` method.

For example:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
  
test_dataset = load_dataset("json", data_files="test.json", split="train")

test_dataset.save_to_disk("test.hf")
```

Comment: Hey! This gets saved as an arrow file. Can I save it as a choice of my own? Can I view it as a normal text file?

Answer (score 5):

You can save the dataset in any format you like using the to_ function. See the following snippet as an example:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("squad")
for split, split_dataset in dataset.items():
    split_dataset.to_json(f"squad-{split}.jsonl")
```

For more information look at the official Huggingface script: https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/course/videos/save_load_dataset.ipynb#scrollTo=8PZbm6QOAtGO

Answer (score 0):

To save a Huggingface dataset or repo, you can follow these steps:

1. First, make sure you have Git installed on your system. If you don't have it already, you can download and install Git from the official website.
2. Once Git is installed, you need to set up Git LFS (Large File Storage) by running the following command in your terminal:

   ```
   git lfs install
   ```
3. Now, you can clone the Huggingface dataset you want to save using the following command. Replace the URL in the command with the URL of the dataset you want to save:

   ```bash
   git clone https://huggingface.co/datasets/Open-Orca/FLAN
   ```

This saves the Huggingface dataset to your local machine. It's worth noting that this method is better than loading the dataset, as it utilizes the full internet bandwidth and clones the entire repository, ensuring you have a local copy of the dataset for offline use.